# Unique identifier for a .NET Assembly - preferably private

Tags: .net, unique, .net-assembly, identifier

Is there a way to uniquely label/identify a .NET assembly in a manner that is not public?  I know with strong names, the full name is unique.  But this full name is discernible to other resources using visual studio tools.  Other Identifiers embedded in the assembly may also be discernible thru decompilation.

I am looking for a way to have a persistent and unique assembly value that would not be readable by staff who have admin access to a given server where the assembly resides.  For example, a Reflection value that was unique to a given assembly, that was only present at run-time, and always had the same value (other than Assembly.FullName since this can be extruded if you know what tools to use.).